# Post # characters in URL being encoded by HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having a problem building links to my Zendesk instance.

In my script, I pull some ticket information from Zendesk and display it in a web app for some important people. I the table of tickets, I want to include a link to the ticket in Zendesk. In the code, I set the value of the cell at such.

```
var cell = "<td><a href=\"https://mydomain.zendesk.com/agent/#/tickets/"+ticket.id+"\">" + ticket.subject + "</a></td>";
```

However, in the resulting webapp the link shows up as follows:

```
https://mydomain.zendesk.com/agent#%2ftickets%2f1507
```

This link doesn't work. I have checked the string before sending it to the HtmlService, and I don't see anything in the Caja documentation.

Thanks

This code causes the same problem:

```
function doGet() {
  var html = '<html><body><table><tr><th>A Header</th></tr><tr><td><a href="https://mydomain.zendesk.com/agent/#/tickets/1507">aoeuaoue</a></td></tr></table>';
  html += '</body></html>';
  Logger.log(html);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}
```

Comment: I have work-around for now, I can use the old link:https://mydomain.zendesk.com/tickets/1678

Comment: None of the links you have provided works. Must be specific to your login.

Comment: @GTM, obviously.... it says "mydomain". No one names their site "mydomain"...